# Get public properties from a class

Tags: class, python-3.x, properties, public

I would like to get all of the public properties of an instance of a class in Python 3, in a dictionary, with a function `public`, without the help of a function in the class. For example, for an instance of the following class :

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5
        self.__b = 2

    @property
    def c(self):
        return 9

    def d(self):
        return 2
    def __e(self):
        return 2
```

I would like the following dict :

```
{'a': 5, 'c': 9}
```

Thanks in advance for your responses.